# QGIS average/mean Z-value of polygon

Tags: qgis, polygon, qgis-3

I am trying to derive an average/mean Z-value of the GPS measured polygons. The standard `z($geometry)` I use for point layers doesn't work obviously. I could use `z(start_point($geometry))`, but that is only the first point.

Is this possible to derive directly from the polygons, thus without converting the polygones to points? And how would this be possible?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend **Extract Z values** tool in the `Processing Toolbox > Vector geometry`.

(As a sample I created a brown polygon `geom_from_wkt('POLYGON((4 5 2, 4 6 2.5, 7 6 1, 7 5 1))')`

1. Execute `Extract Z values` tool.
2. Click on a small ellipsis button `[...]` of the `Summaries to calculate` list.
3. Select `Mean` and run the tool.

The tool will produce an `Extracted` layer with which attribute table contains the mean of Z value. (In this example mean of {2.5, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0} is 1.625).

[image]

Comment: I tried finding the 'Extract Z values' command in QGIS 2.18 and QGIS 3.4.3 but it's not there.  What version of QGIS does it come with?

Comment: @jberrio Sorry for this belated reply. It seems the tool was first introduced in QGIS 3.6 (I may be wrong).